# Presence- absence data from point data

Tags: r, raster

Please I really need your help. 
I have a point data ( Lon and Lat ) and I will like to create presence- absence data from it. How can I do this in R?
Example

```
             species        lon   lat
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.25 55.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.75 55.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.25 55.25
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.75 55.25
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.25 55.25
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -133.25 54.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.75 54.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.25 54.75
```

I want the point data to look like this below;

```
LAT: -90:0.25:90 ---> vector LAT 720
LON: -180: 0.25:180 ----> vector LON 1440

 Cell no   PAS
      1      0
      2      0
      3      0
      4      1
      5      0
      6      1
      7      0
      8      0
      9      0
      .
      .
      .
1039680      1
```

That is 720 Lat and 1440 Lon.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?  It is not clear how you are getting the binary output.

Comment: actually I want it in that binary output, I just use that as example. thanks

Comment: it's not clear to me what the rule is to compute 0 or 1, nor what "Column" means

Comment: Am so sorry for asking this question in a very worry way. I have a point data and I will like to create a presence and absence data from it . Column is the total number of cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably an easier way to do this, but I did the following:

1. Create a grid of known resolution
2. Query lon/lat matches and make presence=1 for hits
3. (optional) Convert to matrix

   ```
   # Load data
   df <- read.table(text=
   "species        lon   lat
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.25 55.75
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.75 55.75
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.25 55.25
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.75 55.25
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.25 55.25
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -133.25 54.75
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.75 54.75
   Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.25 54.75
   ",
   header=TRUE
   )
   head(df)

    # create grid
   reso = 0.25
   xs <- seq(-180, 180, by=reso)
   ys <- seq(-90, 90, by=reso)
   grd <- expand.grid(
     x=xs,
     y=ys,
     presence=0
   )
   head(grd)

   # query
   for(i in seq(nrow(df))){
     tmp <- which(df$lon[i] == grd$x & df$lat[i] == grd$y)
     if(length(tmp)>0){
       grd$presence[tmp] <- 1
     }
   }

   png("plot.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=600, type="cairo")
   plot(grd$x, grd$y, pch=1, cex=1, col=c(NA, 1)[grd$presence+1], lwd=0.5)
   dev.off()
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   mat <- list(x=xs, y=ys, z=matrix(grd$presence, nrow=length(xs), ncol=length(ys)))
   png("mat.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=600, type="cairo")
   image(mat, useRaster=TRUE, col=c(NA, 1))
   dev.off()
   ```

If you zoom in on the matrix, you'll see the presence grids in black.

Comment: This works great, thanks. However, how can I expand the grid the cover the whole -180, 180, -90, 180 by 0.25. Thank you so much

Comment: The example now has the expanded grid, and an optional conversion to a matrix for easier plotting.

Comment: Perfect, this should work also, but I figure out how to make the first code into the full grids . Thanks so much

Comment: it solved the problem with regular Lon and Lat , but not with irregular ones like this  35.41515 24.98915
36.0443 14.2512
36.533 -6.3
36.83 10.25
37.87157 -0.32839
37.8741 -0.44197
37.87651 -0.55556
37.87881 -0.66917
37.9616 -0.32513
37.96413 -0.43885
37.96656 -0.55258
37.96887 -0.66632
37.99046 15.42379
38.05163 -0.32186
38.05417 -0.43571
38.0566 -0.54958  thanks for your help